# How to use "React.useState()" in const classes in React

Tags: reactjs, react-native

In this code, I am not able to use const [ isAlertVisible, setIsAlertVisible ] inside/outside of const FoodRow.js file.
How to fix this code? This is entire code which I am using.
Along with that, I am also placing .css file.

Alert is not getting displayed. Also on button click, Entire view goes away where, I am using FoodRow.js. Screen becomes blank.

```
import React from 'react'
import {View, Text,StyleSheet  } from 'react-native';
import './FoodRow.css';


const FoodRow = (props) => {
    const [ isAlertVisible, setIsAlertVisible ] = React.useState(false);
    const addToCartClick = () => {
        console.log("addToCartClick");
        setIsAlertVisible(true);
    
            setTimeout(() => {
                setIsAlertVisible(false);
           }, 3000);
           console.log("addToCartClick , isAlertVisible = "+isAlertVisible);
    }
    return (
      <View style={{flex:1, flexDirection: 'row'}}>
    
      
        <Text style = {styles.restaurantName}>{props.title }</Text> 
        <Text style = {styles.restaurantNameDesc}>{props.price }</Text> 
        <button style={{backgroundColor: "blue" , width: "100px", height: "20px"}}  onClick={addToCartClick}>
            Add To Cart
        </button>
        
        {isAlertVisible && <div className='alert-container'>
               <div className='alert-inner'>Alert! Alert!</div>
           </div>   }
      
      </View>
    )
}



export default FoodRow

const styles = StyleSheet.create ({
  container: {
     alignItems: 'center',
     marginTop: 100,
     padding: 20
  },
  restaurantName: {
    color: 'red',
     fontSize: 30,
     fontStyle: 'italic',
     paddingLeft: 100,
     marginTop: 50
  },
  restaurantNameDesc: {
    color: 'black',
     fontSize: 20,
     fontStyle: 'italic',
     paddingLeft: 100
  },
  capitalLetter: {
     color: 'red',
     fontSize: 20
  },
  wordBold: {
     fontWeight: 'bold',
     color: 'black'
  },
  italicText: {
     color: '#37859b',
     fontStyle: 'italic'
  },
  textShadow: {
     textShadowColor: 'red',
     textShadowOffset: { width: 2, height: 2 },
     textShadowRadius : 5
  }
})
```

FoodRow.css:

```
.alert-container {
    position: absolute;
    top: 2rem;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
  }
  
  .alert-inner {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 8px 16px;
    z-index: 1;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    box-shadow: 1px 2px 10px -3px rgb(0 0 0 / 70%);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 2px 10px -3px rgb(0 0 0 / 70%);
    -moz-box-shadow: 1px 2px 10px -3px rgb(0 0 0 / 70%);
  }
```

Comment: it is because you are using in the return of the component, you need to use it in the render change "(. to "{ and all the JSX inside a `return (... jsx here)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move function addToCartClick to component, like this:

```
import React from 'react'
import {View, Text,StyleSheet, Button } from 'react-native';
                
        
const FoodRow = (props) => {
        const [ isAlertVisible, setIsAlertVisible ] = React.useState(false);
        
        const addToCartClick = () => {
            console.log("addToCartClick");
            setIsAlertVisible(true);
        
                setTimeout(() => {
                    setIsAlertVisible(false);
               }, 3000);
        }
        return (
          <View style={{flex:1, flexDirection: 'row'}}>
                <Text style = {styles.restaurantName}>{props.title }</Text> 
                <Text style = {styles.restaurantNameDesc}>{props.price }</Text> 
                <Button style={{backgroundColor: "blue" , width: "100px", height: "20px"}}  onPress={addToCartClick}>
                    Add To Cart
                </Button >
                
                {isAlertVisible && <View className='alert-container'>
                       <Text className='alert-inner'>Alert! Alert!</Text >
                   </View >   
                 }
              
          </View>
        )
 }
    
    
export default FoodRow
```

Another thing is that you are using react native but alert is displayed as a "div", you should change it to View and Text, and import button from react-native. However if you want to style your button a bit more I suggest using TouchableOpacity

Comment: Hi, Alert is still not getting visible. Can you share some code to show alert on button click and then it should   automatically get removed in 2 seconds? I am new to React.

Comment: update your question with new code and we will see, plus in react native you don't have onClick if I remember well but onPress event

Comment: And when I click on button, Entire view go away, where I use this FoodRow.js.

Comment: ok As I said before, you can't use div in react native, button is not imported, plus still onClick event is present eventho it is not valid, another thing is that if View go away then in terminal you should have described why app crashed.  I will update my answer, give me a sec